# How to center drawable image and text in a RadioButton?

Tags: android

I am trying to center both the image and text in the center of the radio button. Here is my code :-

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:background="@drawable/left_button_unselected"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="Latest"
        android:textColor="@color/offblack"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
```

However by doing this, the image is at the left end and whatever i try to do, the image does not comes in the centre like in the image below. Please help
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple gist for that. check it out: https://gist.github.com/siyamed/7278413851d3a1d02ffc

Comment: This should be accepted as a true solution! You nailed it, @Siyamed. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/left_button_unselected"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="Latest"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not Helpful. That drawable is the shadow effect you see in the background

Comment: see my edited answer. add android:button="@drawable/ic_launcher" and delete android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: It is coming on the extreme left and not in the center

Comment: use relative layout and add android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" remove gravity, give width 100dp, it is working to me

Comment: This is a radio button. I dont want a relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

You just use the Linear Layout for this problem you can solve it easily.....
You this below Code it will use definitely for you...
And the below code Image View is....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawableImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```