# Trying to implement a group of radio buttons with center text and image in android

Tags: android

i am trying to implement a group of radio buttons (**like in the first image below**) in a radio group because i want to achieve only one button click at a time so the solutions like :-

- Create a relative layout and add an imageview and a text will not work here because i want to click only one radio button like a single select view , For example :-

Select Gender:- ( Can select only one at a time )

Male

Female

Please refer to this question i asked earlier :- [How to center drawable image and text in a RadioButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430741/how-to-center-drawable-image-and-text-in-a-radiobutton)

However, i can create a group of radio button, but the issue is that **i want fixed width radio buttons with center text and image on its left**
This is the code i am using to create a group of radio button :-

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Latest"
        android:textColor="@color/offblack" />
     <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Latest"
        android:textColor="@color/offblack" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your using android:layout_width="150dp" on the radiobutton. The drawable gets sets at the left of the total radiobutton, not the text withing the button. If you use android:layout_width="wrap_content" the image is directly to the left of the radiobutton.

Depending on the layout you want to achieve you may have to add some padding/margin to the radiobutton(s) and/or group(s).

Comment: Yes i know this but i want all the buttons to be of same width irrespective of the text in it. Sorry, i didn't mentioned this, but currently i am using the "wrap_content" approach only but by this the buttons are of variable width. I want same width with image and text in center

Comment: Is there any other group view with single selection or any library ?